# Length of array is different inside the Javascript than it is inside the modal the Javascript opens

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code

```
console.log($scope.newUserTags.length);
$('#clarifyFactTitles').modal('show');
console.log($scope.newUserTags.length);
```

In the modal that opens I have `{{newUserTags.length}}` and I printed the same statement on the main page.

In the JS code it logs `4` before and after opening the modal, but in the modal itself and the main page, it display `3`.

As a result, the `ng-repeat` I have in the modal also only display the first 3 elements.

I'm at a total loss where my last element could have disappeared too.

One extra clue I have is that this bug ONLY happens when the last 'factTitle' is pushed in `$scope.checkForNewUserTags()`. If the last one isn't pushed (i.e. it's already a userTag), it behave normally.

This AngularJS v1.2.19

EDIT: added a lot more context code

```
  $scope.createUserTags = function() {
    console.log($scope.newUserTags);
    $http.post('/user/questions/add', $scope.newUserTags).success(function(res) {
      let files = document.getElementById('userUploadFile').files;
      $scope.actualUserUpload(files)
    });
  };

  $scope.isFactTitleAlreadyUserTag = async function(factTitle) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      $http.get(`/usertags/facttitle/${factTitle}`).success(function(res) {
        return resolve(res.isUserTag);
      });
    });
  };

  $scope.checkForNewUserTags = async function(factTitles) {
    $scope.newUserTags = [];
    for(let i in factTitles){
      let res = await $scope.isFactTitleAlreadyUserTag(factTitles[i]);
      if(res === false) {
        console.log({"factTitle": factTitles[i]});
        $scope.newUserTags.push({"factTitle": factTitles[i]});
        console.log($scope.newUserTags.length);
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.actualUserUpload = function(files){
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("csv", files[0]);

    $http.post('/user/upload', fd , {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
      transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("success!");
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("failed!");
    });
  };

  //the save method
  $scope.uploadUserFile = function() {
    let files = document.getElementById('userUploadFile').files;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async function(event) {
      let fileContents = event.target.result;
      let factTitles = fileContents.split('\r')[0].split(',');
      $scope.checkForNewUserTags(factTitles).then(function() {
        // if there are no new userTags to be made
        if($scope.newUserTags.length === 0) {
          $scope.actualUserUpload(files)
        } else {
          // open modal to ask for the types and question title
          console.log($scope.newUserTags.length);
          $('#clarifyFactTitles').modal('show');
          console.log($scope.newUserTags.length);
        }
      })
    };
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  };
```

And here's the modal with the ng-repeat

```
  <div id="clarifyFactTitles" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">We need some more info on your data!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{newUserTags.length}}
          <div ng-repeat="newUserTag in newUserTags">
            <b>Name in CSV:</b> {{newUserTag.factTitle}}
            <div>
              <form>
                <div style="padding-top: 20px" class="form-row">
                  <b style="padding-top: 5px">Type of input:</b>
                  <select class="m-2" ng-model="newUserTag.type">
                    <option value="dropdown">Dropdown</option>
                    <option value="number">Number</option>
                    <option value="words">Words</option>
                    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                  </select>
                </div><br/>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <b>How would you ask this as a question?</b>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="newUserTag.questionTitle" />
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <hr/>
          </div>
          {{newUserTags.length}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="createUserTags()">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Something is changing `$scope.newUserTags`.  We don't have enough code to determine waht that might be though.

Comment: But no code is ran in the modal that would `pop` the `newUserTags`, and DEFINITELY not pop and push the same exact value in place. That's why I tested before AND after. In fact, nowhere in all the code is `newUserTags` changed after the initial `pushing`

Comment: My point remains, though, that we don't have enough code to determine what is happening or why.

Comment: I hear. Thanks for the feedback, Amy. I added the code that I think will contextualize the issue.

Comment: You might consider replacing the value of `$scope.newUserTags` with an instance of the `Proxy` class wrapping the actual value, with a single interceptor containing a log statement.  You can then watch the log and even set a breakpoint, that *might* help you determine what is happening.  Basically you should (emphasis on *should*) be able to monitor every access or mutation of the array.

Comment: Reviewing the code, none of the usual suspects jump out at me.  Could be race condition resulting from the async, maybe, but that's probably reaching.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the knot confused one here. I've been staring at this problem for hours making no progress

Comment: What does the ng-repeat code look like?

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling I edited in the code from he modal. the ng-repeat only repeats three times and `3` is displayed in the modal `newUserTags.length`even though `4` is displayed in the console.

Comment: @bzupnick Are you absolutely certain that `newUserTags` in the modal is referring to the same array instance as `$scope.newUserTags` in the code?  I see a limited number of possibilities here.  (1) the array is being modified (ruled out?), (2) its not the same array, but looks very very similar, (3) demons.

Comment: @Amy I thought of that too. I made sure to copy and paste it so there's no errors, and there's no other array named the same thing. Also note my edit with an additional clue. I'll copy and paste it here:  One extra clue I have is that this bug ONLY happens when the last 'factTitle' is pushed in `$scope.checkForNewUserTags()`. If the last one isn't pushed (i.e. it's already a userTag), it behaves normally.

Comment: the new clue, I thought, points to a race condition, but if I keep adding, the ng-repeat acts normally as if the last one isn't pushed. A race condition would just ALWAYS stop at around the same index

Comment: You could either try `$watch` that variable for any changes or try passing `newUserTags.length` as a parameter to the model itself instead of calling `.length` inside of it.

Comment: Try using ControllerAs with vm syntax as described here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controlleras-with-vm